# PyCharm phantom files in changelist

Tags: mercurial, pycharm, changelist

I love PyCharm (and IntelliJ). However, in PyCharm for Max OSX, using Mercurial VCS, I get what I call "phantom files" in my changelists as I work. I don't know why they appear and I don't know how to stop them from appearing. By "phantom files", I mean files that actually exist, but are shown in green font, and Show Diff shows them as having an empty file on the left, and the complete file on the right. Sometimes they're files I've actually changed since last commit, sometimes not. If I've changed the file, the file appears twice in the changelist, once as a phantom file in green font, and again in blue font where Show Diff shows the actual updates.

Comment: Please file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with more details, specify what VCS you are using.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Per your request, I've created the following issue: PY-9178. I added that this was for Mercurial. I don't know what other detail to supply.